# How to resume downloads after app was killed

Tags: swift, urlsession

As I read from other topics for redownloading files we need to impelement this method

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                             task: URLSessionTask,
                             didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
```

get data from error._userInfo and resume download process with

```
session.downloadTask(withResumeData: data)
```

I have tried to test this, but it is never call this method after killing app in a simulator, is there anything else that I should do, or doesnt it work in simulator?

Thanks.